# ons.notification.* generate an error

Tags: onsen-ui

I use onsen-ui v1.3.14.

When I try to use every function in ons.notification, I get an error :

Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'window.navigator.userAgent.match')
isAndroid@file://.../onsenui_all.min.js:18:8206

And subsequently :

TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'alertDialog.show')
createAlertDialog onsenui_all.min.js:17:19361

The code is quite simple :

```
ons.notification.alert({
    message: "Message.",
    title: "Title",
    buttonLabel: "OK"
});
```

Comment: Is there anything in your app or your browser that modifies `userAgent`?

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. I had a var called navigator. I was just following the doc's examples. And this one was a bad example. It causes a name conflict with window.navigator.

Comment: Where in the docs is that written? Please point it out so we can change it. We usually name it `myNavigator` for that reason.

Comment: It's quite old now. Maybe the docs have changed. Now I often see myNavigator or app.navi. I just found one example [here](https://onsen.io/guide/overview.html#UsingOnsenUIwithAngularJS). Some code portions uses navigator like in [this chapter](https://onsen.io/guide/overview.html#Transitionanimation). But it's not in the var attribute of the ons-navigator html element.

Comment: Those should be considered as local variables, just as this other: https://onsen.io/guide/overview.html#ComponentInitEvent
Anyway we will make new docs for 2.0 and we won't use "navigator" to avoid misunderstandings like this.